# Java GET request with HttpURLConnection not working as expected

Tags: java, http, url, http-proxy, get-request

I am using core java to retrieve single web page content as String using proxy.

```
    private static HttpURLConnection getConnection(String urlStr) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("216.56.48.118", 9000));
            HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
            return uc;
        }

public static void printHomePageContent() throws Exception {

        String queryParam = URLEncoder.encode(
                "YBuD64pgMuP3hiqNmR4hB6H8xdAebeBPfdEPbdNUq3ptkbhSYGkdhuKaPCXE+KXT3unjfaI3tRJzQno10f/FiC7IzNAdhbrPK9d4smyxHpE=",
                "UTF-8");
        HttpURLConnection conn = getConnection(
                "https://www.example.com?params=" + queryParam);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        conn.connect();

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;) {
            System.out.print((char) c);
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** `www.example.com` is replaced with the actual url as I can't share it in public, all other things are exactly same as my original code.

**PROBLEM:** When I call `printHomePageContent` it's printing wrong page(same page if I don't send query param) content that means it's not considering `params` query parameter value as expected. While if If I hit the same URL on browser or POSTMAN(Rest Client), it's displaying right page. `I am using proxy from browser as well using chrome extension.`

I know you can't replicate the issue your own as I have replaced the URL, but the description I wrote is exactly what is happening. If anybody can suggest some hints based on their past experienced would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe the site uses cookies and you do not submit

Comment: @mrmcwolf : then browser or POSTMAN should not return the right results, I am not submitting any cookies there

Comment: can send them automatically. you may also need a specific header.
look at the query that the browser sends and repeats it 1:1.
unfortunately, no precise site address can be said nothing specifically

Comment: Keep in mind that URLConnection follows the auramatic redirects with code 3**

Comment: Can you confirm that value of `queryParam` is exactly same as in POSTMAN?

Comment: @rkosegi : it's confirmed, exact same

Comment: @mrmcwolf : what do you mean by your last comment? Can you explain a bit with example?

Comment: open the browser development tools and select the network tab. then run your request.
so you will see exactly what the browser is sending and what the server does.
copy the request headers (use `URLConnection::setRequestProperty`).

Comment: @mrmcwolf : Do you want me to send highlighted cookies in my code? http://prntscr.com/guc7x3 Also, can you help me that why I am getting 200(with wrong page) while in these headers it's 302. Also, how these cookies came with browser?

Comment: URLConnection automatically follows the redirect specified by the Location header, but does not save the cookies that are being set.
the easiest option to solve this problem is to register `CookieManager` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html

Comment: Sounds interesting and helpful, but is it possible to help with modifying above code?

Comment: add this `CookieHandler.setDefault (new CookieManager ());` before `HttpURLConnection conn = getConnection (...`
I am currently on the phone and I can not work properly with code.

Comment: that's not working but I got some direction to think on that, thanks